# Swift code crashes on [String:String] to URLQueryItem conversion

Tags: swift

I initialise `[String:String]` like this

```
func doInBackground() {
....
    var getData = [String:String]()
    getData["domainOrGroupId"] = "5"
    getData["driverId"] = "2"
    getData["authKey"] = "998099"
```

I then try to convert the same to `[URLQueryItem]`

```
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

    for key in getData.keys {
       print(key+":"+getData[key as String]! as String)
       queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name : key, value : getData[key])) 
    }
```

Crash's on line `queryItems.append`

What am I missing ? Something really basic I suppose.

**EDIT**

Attached breakpoint at `var queryItems =`

```
getData [String : String]   3 key/value pairs   
[0] (key: String, value: String)    
[1] (key: String, value: String)    
[2] (key: String, value: String)
```

Hit `Step Over` until `print` **notice I have moved `print` before `queryItems.append`.**

prints ok

```
 driverId:2
```

**What happens**

Hit `Step Over` one more time, the debugger disappears XCode displays a dialog `Test Succeeded`. I guess this means **My app CRASHED**

**What was expected**

Hit 'Step Over' just iterates over the `getData` in the `for in` loop.

**EDIT**

I was running the method inside a DispatchQueue.global async. And the program was completing before the doInBackground had a chance to run. That was the root cause of my debugger not running ok.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.doInBackground()
```

Comment: Assuming `getData` == `parameters` – your code compiles and runs fine. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Fixed the minor error.

Comment: Your code still compiles and runs fine.

Comment: It isn't working for me brother.

Comment: Copy and paste it into a new project – it compiles and runs fine in both Swift 3.0.2 and 3.1. Your problem is likely elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Trying that. Will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `getData` contains the `parameters` dictionary just use the API to enumerate a dictionary:

```
var parameters = [String:String]()
parameters["domainOrGroupId"] = "5"
parameters["driverId"] = "2"
parameters["authKey"] = "98098"


var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

for (key, value) in parameters {
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name : key, value : value))
    print(key+":"+value)
}
```

or even in one line using `map`

```
queryItems = parameters.map{ URLQueryItem(name : $0.0, value : $0.1) }
```

Comment: Crashs at `queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name : key, value : value))`

Comment: Then `parameters` != `getData`. The code compiles and runs fine. What error reason do you get?

Comment: Test session log:
 /MyPath/Logs/Test/D7584BF5-F4C5-47F8-900F-0153AE9E40B2/Session-MyAppTests-2017-02-25_181159-20kR4l.log

Comment: Do you really expect that I can read your local files on your hard disk? ;-)

Comment: Oh no, I'm just sharing the info so that you can guide me on next steps.

Comment: Related to you **EDIT**: Are you kidding? `Test Succeeded` means everything went well. Success / green == good, Failed / red == bad.

Comment: Dude, If I step thru the code and hit "Step Over" it hsould just run a step ahead right ? As of now "Step Over" is behaving like "RUN".

Comment: Basically I was calling the method on inside a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. As it was a async call, it just got killed after the program / test case finished.